# Old eth network accounts do not appear after reinstalling metamask

Tags: metamask, cpp-ethereum

I have a serious problem.
I switched from Note and in the new Note I restored Metamask using my phrases.
The installation worked.
Inside the Metamask of the old note I had the ETH network with two accounts and the BSC network with one account.
When restoring, only the BSC account with balances and ETH’s without balance appeared.
When I look up the public key from the ETH wallet the tokens are there. I’ve tried to reinstall in other browsers and other notes but without success.
Has anyone ever experienced this?
Need help.
Thanks

Comment: Do you still have those accounts' private keys?

Comment: Is the same address on both? If you were using a secondary account in Metamask you have to use the option to add another address. If the token balances do not appear you have to add them manually since state isn't synchronized across installations.

Comment: I have the 12 words of Metamask. I've tried to manually add more accounts and all of them are reset, even including the manual tokens and all of them are reset.